# Checkbox-Trick not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to use the checkbox-trick to show my mobile navbar. Somehow the h1 isn't showin up even when the invisible checkbox is checked. What have I done wrong?

```css
#label {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 47px;
}


h1 {
display: none
}
#toggle {
  display: none;
}


#toggle:checked + h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburgermenu">
  <label id="label" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
</div>

<h1>DEMO ELEMENT</h1>
```

Comment: Can't be displayed: If any element is invisible, ALL of its descendants are invisible, too. Your h1 is a child element of your (invisible) checkbox, so although it itself is displayed as a block, the whole container (the checkbox) is invisible at all. Also this is not valid HTML, a checkbox can't have any other child elements at all.

Comment: @Psi How, do you see the h1 be a child of checkbox? Don't provide misleading information, the reason is the CSS selector which is in play here.

Comment: Use JavaScript for this `.checked` is `boolean` after listening listen to `change` instead of `click`.

Comment: @RonRoyston There's no javascript tag on the question. So, I think it would be better and appreciated to provide a pure CSS solution.

Comment: @NoahAdler It'd be appreciated to mark the solution as accepted if it solved your query. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You're using "**+**" which is a `sibling CSS selector`, but `<h1>` isn't a sibling of your checkbox. It's a **sibling of the checkbox's parent container**. You can have 3 ways to go about it.

**First way:** Make it the sibling of the input by placing it inside

```css
#label {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 47px;
}

h1 {
  display: none
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked+h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburgermenu">
<label id="label" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">

<h1>DEMO ELEMENT</h1>
</div>
```

**Second way:** Make it the sibling of the input by taking the input out of the container

```css
#label {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 47px;
}

h1 {
  display: none
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburgermenu">
<label id="label" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
</div>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<h1>DEMO ELEMENT</h1>
```

**Third way:** Make use of javascript.

Comment: Only the checkbox needs to be moved outside of the div. The label can stay inside.

Comment: @René Oh, that's witty :)